# Selenium Grid Hub shutdown command

Tags: c#, selenium, grid

Is there a command (from the command line or a webrequest) to shut down a grid 2.0 hub?

I have tried "curl -d action=shutdown http://localhost:4444/lifecycle-manager" (as POST request), I have also tried the usual http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

I've searched everywhere. I would preferably like something without using rake or ant

Comment: Did you see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969495/stopping-asp-webdev-and-selenium-servers-from-command-line

Comment: the accepted answer does not work with the grid 2.0 hub. I was wondering if an equivalent command exists for the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At version 2.25.0 old-style hub managing [added](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG).

So now you can use request like this one to stop hub:

```
http://localhost:4444/lifecycle-manager?action=shutdown
```